# Okhttp3: Add global header to all requests error

Tags: java, okhttp, interceptor

I would like to define a global header for all my requests. I am using okhttp3.
I searched here in the forum and found an approach, which I tried to implement:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    httpClient.networkInterceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .method("GET", null)
                    .addHeader("Accept", headerType)
                    .addHeader(headerAuthorization, headerAuthorizationValue)
                    .build();

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(Connection.BASE_URL)
            .build();

    okhttp3.Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
    String responseData = response.body().string();
    System.out.println(responseData);
}
```

However, I get an error during execution and I think it is related to the Interceptor. The exception is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:1062)
at jira.Program.main(Program.java:25)
```

Does anyone see what my mistake is and can help me please? Best thanks in advance!

Comment: which is line 25?

Comment: line 25 is httpClient.networkInterceptors().add(new Interceptor()

Comment: please read my answer on why it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation
`httpClient.networkInterceptors()`

> Returns an immutable list of interceptors that observe a single network request and response.

Since it is an immutable list you can not add elements to it, i.e. an `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown on `networkInterceptors().add(...)`

EDIT:

In order to fix this, please replace `new OkHttpClient();`

with `new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(...).build()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have now understood that. Because of this I replaced "networkInterceptors()" with "Interceptors()", but the same error occurs, although Interceptors should "Returns a modifiable list of interceptors..." if I understand correctly.

Comment: no, same here: "Returns an immutable list of interceptors"...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I changed it to: httpClient.newBuilder().interceptors().add(new Interceptor()... Now it is working but is this right? Looks weird to me.

Comment: Please build your HttpClient differently as update in my answer

Comment: @qwertz yes, it is a common pattern (builder pattern) to use buiilder to create objects instead of constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to use just interceptor instead of network interceptor, because Network interceptors has special use like redirects and retries.