# Okhttp3: Need help to use HeaderInterceptor

Tags: java, okhttp, interceptor

I would like to use a global header for all my requests. Therefore I have implemented the following class:

```
public class HeaderInterceptor {

    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request()
                .newBuilder()
                .method("GET", null)
                .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                .addHeader("Basic ", "abcdefghi123456789")
                .build();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        return response;
    }

}
```

Now I would like to do the following in the main()-method:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(MyInterceptor).build();

        Request reqAllProjects = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://example.com/projects")
                .build();

        Response resAllProjects = httpClient.newCall(reqAllProjects).execute();

        String responseData = resAllProjects.body().string();

        System.out.println(responseData);

 }
```

I'm not sure now how to use my HeaderInterceptor. I guess I'll have to enter it here, right?
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(**??MyInterceptor??**).build();
I tried something like this: addInterceptor(HeaderInterceptor.intercept()) but this is not working...

Can someone help me please? And does the rest of it look fine? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interceptor class that you have created doesn't seem to be implementing the `Interceptor` interface. You need to implement as below

```
public class HeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request()
                .newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                .addHeader("Basic ", "abcdefghi123456789")
                .build();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        return response;
    }  
}
```

Do note that you **should not** be modifying the method and body of the request as `.method("GET", null)` unless you actually need so, as it can result in all the HTTP requests made by the client to make GET requests with null body.

Then add the interceptor while building the client as below

```
    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                 .addInterceptor(new HeaderInterceptor()).build();
```

Have a look at the OkHttp [documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/#rewriting-requests) for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have now implemented it as you suggested. But now I have following errors: 
 - The method intercept(Interceptor.Chain) of type HeaderInterceptor must override 
           a superclass  method
 - implements okhttp3.Interceptor.intercept                                                                                         It seems like I need to import okhttp3.interceptor.intercept... But import okhttp3.interceptor.intercept; does not work... How can I import it? I thought "import okhttp3.interceptor;" was enough, but apparently not.

Comment: I had used Java 1.5 in the project. After I updated it to 1.6, it works...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this question : [Okhttp3: Add global header to all requests error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61701646/okhttp3-add-global-header-to-all-requests-error/61701797#61701797)

It should be something like
    .addInterceptor(new Interceptor())